# Excel formula challenge

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Create an Excel formula that will randomly insert the symbol "✓" into a range of cells `(B1-B5)` based on a value entered in cell `A1`. For example, if the value 4 is entered in `A1`, then four cells within the `B1-B5` range should have the "✓" symbol inserted at random.

i tried

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW($B$1)+1<= $A$1, "✓", "")
```

but the symbol is not randomly assign to each box

Comment: The checkmark is a character in the "Symbol" font.  You can use chr(248) to insert the character, but there is nothing in EXCEL formulas that will set the font family to Symbol.  You have to do that part manually or in a VBA macro.

Comment: If you're using Excel365, use [`RandArray`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/randarray-function-21261e55-3bec-4885-86a6-8b0a47fd4d33) to generate random and `If( random array > threshold,  tick, "")`

Comment: Off-topic: The title is interesting to me since it would be nice to be able to post Excel-formula challenges. Does someone know if such a stack exchange community exists?

Comment: Highly doubt your creativity from Code Golf and the such could be contained within Excel  formulas only, haven't seen any community for it at least. Might be too specific/less fun for most.

Comment: @Notus_Panda, right. Hindsight Code Golf (despite the communitie's name) could be just the place. I found that one could use the tag `code-challenge` which would mean: *"A code challenge is a competition for creative ways to solve a programming puzzle with an objective winning criterion not covered by other scoring tags (e.g. code-golf)."*. It's just not specific to Excel unfortunately.

Comment: you can try this @Germz002
 =IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,$A$1+2)>$A$1,"","✓")

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=SORTBY(IF(ROW(1:5)<=A1,"✓",""),RANDARRAY(5))
```

Or:

```
=SORTBY(REPT("✓",ROW(1:5)<=A1),RANDARRAY(5))
```

---

Strictly speaking the above handles the given restrictions well. Though, as pointed out below, a more rigorous option could be:

```
=LET(total_rows,5,total_ticks,4,SORTBY(REPT("✓",SEQUENCE(total_rows)<=total_ticks),RANDARRAY(total_rows)))
```

Where the `5` and `4` could also be references to given cells holding these integers.

Comment: `ROW(1:5)` is not very rigorous. This isn't a shortest formula challenge! :-)

Comment: Fair point! Not very rigorous, but would tick the given restrictions (a given set range) just fine. Let me add a less strict option in case these restrictions where to be interpreted loosely @JosWoolley.

Comment: is it possible to use this formula to excel professional plus 2016? You are a great help btw

Comment: @Germz002, unfortunately these functions would not be available for Excel 2016 users.